# What are the 2D ArrayList equivalents of these ArrayList Functions?

Tags: java, arrays, function, arraylist

This is the initalization.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> names = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

The functions are as follow.

```
    names.add("Amey");
```

and

```
    names.set(a, "Jane");
```

Here is the full program that needs to be turned into a 2D ArrayList. The purpose of the program is to replace John with Jane, wherever John is.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Prac5twodArraylistString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> names = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    names.add("Amey");
    names.add("Aditya");
    names.add("John");
    names.add("Saideep");
    names.add("Shrikar");
    names.add("Sujay");
    for (int a = 0; a <= (names.size()) - 1; a++) {
        System.out.println(names.get(a));
    }
    for (int a = 0; a <= (names.size()) - 1; a++) {
        if (names.get(a).equals("John")) {
            names.set(a, "Jane");
        }
    }
    for (int a = 0; a <= (names.size()) - 1; a++) {
               System.out.println(names.get(a));
    }
   }
  }
```

.Will you please help me with this code?

Comment: In your code you have already replaced "John" with "Jane". So what is your question? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Are you asking for a fix to the compile errors?

Comment: and why are you using an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s?

Comment: What seems to be the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't compile. You are creating a `List` of a `List` of `String` and you are trying to add just a `String` to it instead of a `List` of `String`.

When you do `names.add("anyName");` you would need to do `names.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{add("name")};`. But then the rest of your code won't work.

If you change

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> names = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

for

`ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();`

your code will compile and work.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant to say that I wanted the 2D ArrayList equivalents of these Array functions. I am very Sorry.

Comment: would you care to explain what is a 2D ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding I feel that your problem lies with your 2D `ArrayList`. The line `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> names = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` means that you variable `names` is actually an `ArrayList` of other `ArrayList<String>`. So your code `name.add("SomeString")` will show an error as the parameter expected in this method is `ArrayList<String>` but you are supplying it with `String`.

Now If you require to have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` Then you have to declare an new variable of `ArrayList<String>` Like this:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
```

The add the names to this `temp` object like this instead of the `name` object:

```
temp.add("Amey");
temp.add("Aditya");
temp.add("John");
temp.add("Saideep");
temp.add("Shrikar");
temp.add("Sujay");
```

Now add this `temp` object to the `names` object like this:

```
names.add(temp);
```

For printing out your contents you have to use this loop:

```
   for(ArrayList<String> a : names){
      for(String name: a){
         System.out.println(name);
      }
   }
```

For replacing "John" with "Jane" you could use the following:

```
   for(ArrayList<String> a : names){
      if(a.contains("John")){
         a.set(a.indexOf("John"), "Jane");
      }
   }
```

Comment: I am sorry. I meant to say that I wanted the 2D ArrayList equivalents of these Array functions. I am very Sorry.